# Is there a way to suppress null data values in a line chart using dimple.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dimple.js

I am looking to suppress missing values in a line graph using dimple.js, and I would like functionality equivalent to the `svg.line().defined()` method in d3.js: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090

I attempted to modify the `dimple.plot.line` object to add in the `.defined` portion, but this did not seem to work. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Methods like `Array.prototype.forEach()` only access defined array items, if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Pretty much the same question [*"dimple.js - show gaps in line chart"*](/q/27263330) was asked a year ago, yet there was no answer.

Comment: There is a [comment](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_dynamic_line_color#comment-1318129807) on one of the advanced examples on dimples.js which asks for something similar. The answer to that refers to [*"dimple.js Show X Axis label, but if “value” is null don't place a circle on chart"*](/q/21291628) which might help.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It appears that the line plotting function does not work as easy as changing the opacity of bubbles. Continuing the search!